# Loading a class with custom ClassLoader without using a String

Tags: java, class, classloader, in-memory

I have created a custom ClassLoader and want to load a class. I am using this code at the moment to load the class from the Jar:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream byteIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    JarInputStream jarIS = new JarInputStream(byteIS);
    JarEntry je;
    je = jarIS.getNextJarEntry();
    byte[] classbytes = new byte[(int) je.getSize()];
    jarIS.read(classbytes, 0, classbytes.length);
    jarIS.close();
    CustomClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
    classLoader.setClassContent(classbytes);
    Class c = classLoader.findClass("Main");
    Object object = c.newInstance();
    Method[] methods = object.getClass().getMethods();
    Object returnValue = methods[0].invoke(null, new Object[]{new String[]{}});
```

In this sample above you can clearly see I am trying to load class Main. Now imagine that my friend also creates a Jar, I cannot know on beforehand what the name of the class is. How can I avoid the usage of a String as argument?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the use of a String?

Comment: Because I would like to change the content. The classname won't always be the same.

Comment: Huh? Then how would you identify the class?

Comment: That's what I'm asking :-)

Comment: No, which class do you want? Can you describe by which criteria you want to select a class?

Comment: Can you specify? Maybe we should take this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68772/discussion-between-k-g-and-manyquestions).

Comment: You've got to specify the class (or at least class file) somehow.  The class file is presumably loaded in a file system, so unless you have, say, the INODE number of the file, you need to have something resembling a name.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you commenting on the latest edit I made, because the time difference between it and your reply isn't that big.

Comment: In answer to your final line, that why Java has "packages".

Comment: You see, ClassLoaders are quite new to me but this makes me want to understand more :/ I'm putting a bounty on this tomorrrow..

Comment: A string is fine, just use a string variable and pass its value as a parameter to the method that contains the code above.

Comment: You understand, don't you, that I can load class Main in my class loader, and then you can load a different version of class Main in your class loader.  They're two separate classes, because they were loaded by different class loaders.  (And yes, your head will explode if you think about that too much.)

Comment: Jup. Do you understand my question or is my question retarded.

Comment: Are you trying to load the class that contains the main method? If so, there is a JAR Attribute in most JAR files that defines the location of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [ServiceLoader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#dictionary-service-example). You can define a common interface for service implementations (classes) that you don't know *a priori*.